# static methods on objects to give a general order

Tags: libgdx, static-methods

I have a class

```
public class Enemy {
...
public static void die(){
    //send order to die or stop
    //System.out.println("enemy dying");
}
```

}

and then create many enemies with a for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i< 5 ; i++){
    enemy = new Enemy();
}
```

I would like to give the order Enemy.die() but can only get the last one created to do the code, is this possible or should I have to go through each enemy created and call die().
the scenario is that there are many enemies that are the same and there is an explosion and all die at the same time

Comment: You need to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates what you're doing. How does your static function tell the enemies to do? Put together a **small** example program that uses print statements to show us what you're doing.

Comment: I don't have the complete code, what Im trying to find out if that if its possible before starting to code. the main question is can I create many instances of enemy, all with the method die() that practically stops them in their tracks and can I give a command to all of them without having to go through each one of them. basically create 100 objects enemy, call Enemy.die(), and all of them stop, or do I have to go one by one and call die();

Comment: Sorry if im not very clear, Im pretty much starting with this

Comment: I suppose you could write a static function that changes some static variable that each instance accesses, but that doesn't sound like **less** work than just looping through all of them.

Comment: You will have to loop through all of them at some point in the update method, right? So one way to do it is give them all an `update` method that takes `shouldDie` as a parameter. Another way to do it if you don't like that would be to set a static variable `shouldDie` to true, and in their `update` methods all the enemies can reference that to decide whether to die. I can't think of a way to use a static method to send a message to a bunch of objects that you are not going to loop through, because if no method is called on them, they won't know to respond to the message.

Comment: Thanks, I created a list of objects and looped through all sending the order, it works fine